# Issue with animating width and display in Nav

Tags: css, html, animation, navigation, css-transitions

Problem is simple...  I have a nav structure which I have animated heights and widths for the subnavs where appropriate.

In this version: http://jsfiddle.net/PmFxZ/3/

I have `display: none;` and (on `:hover`) `display: block;` for my Tier 2 and higher subnavs.

This allows the structure to work fine, but it disallows the width animations.

In this version: http://jsfiddle.net/PmFxZ/4/

The display: none; is set to display: block;.  This allows the width animations to operate.  But causes another issue.  That is, if you hover over About > Our Team > Kenny - it also hovers over the child of "Something"

Is there any way around using display: none/block; to allow the hover states to operate correctly, but also allow the width animations to play?

Answer (score 0):

Found a good solution to this.  The UL's are absolutely positioned relative to their LI parents.  Simply change their `left: 150px;` attribute to `-2000px` then on hover put `left: 150px;` and walaa.  Problem solved.

http://jsfiddle.net/PmFxZ/5/